# Problems instantiating service in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, service, containers

I am having problems loading a service class from my controller in my Symfony application.

The service resides in `ReadathonBundle\Payments\Ipn`:

```
namespace ReadathonBundle\Payments;

class Ipn
{
    private $testVariable;

    /**
     * Ipn constructor.
     * @param $testVariable
     */
    public function __construct($testVariable)
    {
        $this->testVariable = $testVariable;
    }
}
```

I've added the config settings in the services.yml:

```
parameters:
    app.ipn.testVariable: test-value

services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: ReadathonBundle\Form\UserType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }

    app.ipn:
        class:  ReadathonBundle\Payments\Ipn
        arguments: ['%app.ipn.testVariable%']
```

I am trying to call the service in my controller using the following snippet:

```
class PayPalIPNController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * PayPal IPN
     *
     */
    public function listenerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $ipn = $this->get('app.ipn');

        var_dump($ipn->testVariable);

    }
```

This results in a 500 error with the following message:

> Attempted to load class "Ipn" from namespace
>   "ReadathonBundle\Payments". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

I feel that I've missed out something simple somewhere but can't quite put my finger on it.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a right directory structure? Can you post it? Also you are trying to read private property of an object. It is not right and it will not work. Read about encapsulation. And finally: this exception can be thrown from another place because you don't have any code that is trying to load your `Ipn` class.

Comment: As pointed by @MichaelSivolobov verify your directory structure, it may be a typo, the class must be located in `src/ReadathonBundle/Payments/Ipn.php` following the default directory structure. Also, if you are in production, don't forget to clear your cache (looks evident but not always ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will haunt me for a very long time. I spent most of the day on this issue...

It was not working because I didn't have .php at the end of the service class file name, *facepalm*.